# Must call a designated initializer of the superclass 'UIViewController'

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, initializer

I have a class A defined in ObjC and Class B - subclass of A defined in Swift. 
The implementation is as follows:

*Class A*

```
- (id)init {
     return [super init];
}
```

*Class B*

```
init(url: NSURL) {
    super.init()
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    request.setValue(valueID, forHTTPHeaderField: "value_ID")
    urlRequest = request
}

convenience init(recoveryURL: NSURL) {
    self.init(url: recoveryURL)
}

required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

Class B is initialized as follows (since its loaded from the xib file):

```
ClassB *b = [[ClassB alloc] initWithNibName:@"ClassA" bundle:nil];
```

The error is seen on `super.init()` line inside `init(url: NSURL)` of class B. I'm trying to use convenience initializers. I would appreciate if someone can point me @ where am I going wrong?

Comment: Your initialiser isn't calling the designated initialiser of the superclass - refer to "Initializer delegation for class types" in the Swift book.  You will need to pass a nib file to your convenience Initializer or at least have your convenience Initializer specify a nib when it calls the superclass initWithNibName

Answer (score -1):

Consider putting the following code in `viewDidLoad`:

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
request.setValue(k_strOfferingIdValueHeader, forHTTPHeaderField: "offering_id")
urlRequest = request
```

It usually is the cleanest option.